# C++ language feature to simplify naming types (especially in function declarations)

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef, auto

I am wondering if there is a macro or language element in C++ that represents the same type as the return value in a function.

For example:

```
std::vector<int> Myclass::CountToThree() const
{
  std::vector<int> col;
  col.push_back(1);
  col.push_back(2);
  col.push_back(3);
  return col;
}
```

Instead of line `std::vector<int> col;` is there some sort of language element?
I know it is pretty trivial but I am just bored with typing it ;-).

Comment: you can use `typedef` or `using` if you are just too bored typing long type names, like `using vi = std::vector<int>`, and type `vi col;` afterwards.

Comment: You have several options to avoid repeating the actual types of the variables. My advice is that you don't use any of them :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do two things:

1. [Type aliasing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), either **`using`** or **`typedef`**.

   ```
   typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;
   using IntVector = std::vector<int>;
   ```

   These two declarations are equivalent, and provide another name that compiler treats as a synonym of the original name. It can be used for templates as well.

   Why two notations, not just one? The `using` keyword was provided in C++11 [to simplify notation for typedefs in templates](/a/23196675).
2. In C++14, you could use the **`auto`** keyword for automatic return type deduction:

   ```
   auto Myclass::CountToThree() const
   {
       std::vector<int> col;
       col.push_back(1);
       col.push_back(2);
       col.push_back(3);
       return col;
   }
   ```

   For a broader explanation see [this related question](/q/15737223).

Answer (score 2):

For your example, you could just write

```
std::vector<int> Myclass::CountToThree() const
{
    return {1,2,3};
}
```

In general, you can get the return type of a function with `decltype`, but this probably doesn't help in your situation:

```
std::vector<int> Myclass::CountToThree() const
{
  decltype( CountToThree() ) col;
  col.push_back(1);
  col.push_back(2);
  col.push_back(3);
  return col;
}
```